# Error: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am new to pytesseract and OCR and I searched on the internet that this are the tools that is used to extract text from images. But, I have no prior knowledge of this tool. Right now, I am having this error: **tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.**
I don't know how to resolve this and I tried various solutions that I found on internet, which unfortunately didn't worked.

The error code:

```
TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more information.
```

Corresponding code:

```
!pip install tesseract
import pytesseract
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread("meter.jpg")
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(data)
# plt.imshow(img)
```

Let me first tell you that I am using Jupyterhub. Actually, I made an account on my university's jupyterhub. Additionally, I searched on net where one can use **'cmd'** and resolve the problem. If so, then please brief me how to do so or I have to contact the Uni admin to solve this problem. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need the tesseract binary in order to run pytesseract, download it and set the path with:     pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '/path/to/tesseract/bin'

Comment: Where can I find tesseract binary?

Comment: You can compile it yourself, or use an already compiled version from your OS repository:  sudo apt install tesseract-ocr && sudo apt install libtesseract-dev. If you install it this way, I think you won't need to run the pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd

Comment: I did adding tesseract-ocr && sudo apt install libtesseract-dev, but I am being asked for a password. How to solve that and yes I don't want this to be asked?

Comment: Well, it's asking for your account password (if you're in sudoers  file), just type your account password there. If you don't want, you'll need to compile it yourself:https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Compiling.html. Won't be easy, so better install it using your package manager (apt)

Comment: I didn't get any space/section to write the password! Where should I write the password?

Comment: Run one by one the above commands: Look at the asnwer below.

Answer (score 10):

Possible cause of this error is that you installed `pytesseract` with `pip` without installing the binary. If that is the case, you can install it as following:

on linux:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
sudo apt install libtesseract-dev
```

on windows: download it from [here](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki) then insert the binary path into your code

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
```

on On Mac:

```
brew install tesseract
```

Comment: I already performed that step, but nothing happened! Still getting same error.

Comment: I have windows 10 as OS @R.Marolahy

Comment: Then I think it should work. Check well if tesseract is installed  in `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe`. Possibly that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows- in Case of the user have installed it for user only the path will be in the user folder
Like :
`C:\Users\<User.Name>\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe`

using same in code works fine

`pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\John.Doe\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'`